# Kato's Euler System for Isogenous Elliptic Curves

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, iwasawa-theory, isogenies

Let $E,E^\prime$ be elliptic curves over $\mathbb{Q}$ and also suppose they are $p$-isogenous. How are the Euler systems corresponding to the two isogenous elliptic curves related, if at all?

Answer (score 4):

They are related because they come from the same element for $X_1(N)$. Suppose $E$ is the one of the two with the smaller degree of the modular parametrisattion $X_1(N)\to E$ of minimal degree.  Then the isogeny $E\to E'$ sends the zeta elements from $E$ to the corresponding zeta elements for $E'$. This is by definition essentially. Conjecturally $E\to E'$ extends to an étale morphism on the Néron models over $\mathbb{Z}_p$. See Stevens' "Stickelberger elements and modular parametrizations of elliptic curves". Of course the dual isogeny $E'\to E$ maps to the elements of $E$ multiplied with the degree of the isogeny.

I spent some time thinking about the integrality of Kato's elements under isogenies, see also the question [Are Kato's zeta elements integral?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/47135/are-katos-zeta-elements-integral). One can deduce that Kato's divisbility for the main conjecture also holds for all curves in the isogeny class when $E[p]$ is reducible and $p$ is odd and semistable.

Comment: Thanks! As I understand, Euler systems "see" the fine Selmer group and therefore knowing isogeny invariance of Coates-Sujatha 'Conjecture A' for elliptic curves over $\mathbb{Q}$ should translate to understanding this question.

Comment: @debanjana But Corollary 3.6 in their paper implies that, if $E$ has a $p$-isogeny defined over $\mathbb{Q}$, then Conjecture A is valid. So there is no need to use Kato's Euler system for this. The isogeny invariance of Conjecture A is only open for general number fields.

Comment: Sujatha's recent paper with Witte (2017), solves it for the CM elliptic curves too and some other cases. We were curious if it is known/ if it is possible to translate isogeny invariance of Conjecture A (over Q) to the language of Euler systems and see if something can be said in general.